# iam using facebook sdk 4.0 cannot login with facebook in fragment

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments

iam using facebook sdk 4.0 cannot login with facebook in fragment 
here is my code

fbLoginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback < LoginResult > () {

```
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            System.out.println("onSuccess");

            String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken()
                    .getToken();
            Log.d("accessToken", accessToken);

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                            Log.d("LoginActivity",
                                    response.toString());
                            try {
                                String id = object.getString("id");
                                try {
                                    URL profile_pic = new URL(
                                            "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large");
                                    Log.d("profile_pic",
                                            profile_pic + "");

                                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                String name = object.getString("name");
                                String email = object.getString("email");
                                String gender = object.getString("gender");
                                String birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("cancel", "onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            System.out.println("onError");
            Log.d("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);

}
```

It never comes in onSucess or in error after log in .it does not change the log in button to logout.what is the problem is there other method to use it from fragment.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
    AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    displayMessage(profile);
}

@Override
public void onCancel() {

}

@Override
public void onError(FacebookException e) {

}


public MainFragment() {

}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {

        }
    };

    profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
            displayMessage(newProfile);
        }
    };

    accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
    profileTracker.startTracking();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}

private void displayMessage(Profile profile) {
    if (profile != null) {
        textView.setText(profile.getName());

    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    profileTracker.stopTracking();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    displayMessage(profile);
}
```

Comment: iam not getting the code could you pease write the full code

Answer (score 1):

Make a method facebookLogIn() as:

```
public void facebookLogIn(){
    FacebookCallback<LoginResult> loginResultFacebookCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Log.e("FB", String.valueOf(accessToken));
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

            if (profile != null) {
                // name.setText("Witam " + profile.getName());
                Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, profile.getFirstName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("FB", "w");
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
        }
    };
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton mBtnFacebook = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    mBtnFacebook.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
    mBtnFacebook.registerCallback(callbackManager, loginResultFacebookCallback);

}
```

and call this method from your onCreate() method.